# sql check constraint age from birthdate

Tags: sql

How can I have a check constraint for `age < 40 from birthdate` when creating a table? 
Something like:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(yy,” Birthdate ”, getdate()) as age
age<40
```

Then how could I have another check constraint when creating table and counting an attribute, grouping it and checking if it's > 6?

Such as below but as a check constraint?

```
select count(attributex) as counter from entityx
group by attributex
having counter>6
```

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  You had MySQL and Oracle, but the code is SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table person (Birthdate date check (DATEDIFF(year,Birthdate,getdate()) < 40))
```

---

```
insert into person (Birthdate) values ('1990-01-01');
```

> (1 row(s) affected)

```
insert into person (Birthdate) values ('1970-01-01');
```

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 7
>   The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CK__person__Birthdat__30F848ED". The conflict occurred in database "dmarkovitz", table "dbo.person", column 'Birthdate'.

Answer (score -1):

Check constraints when creating a table:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp

And for the second question, I guess you want to put a check constraint which would limit the number of rows inserted for a condition like (age > 6 and age < 40). For this it makes more sense to check max limit rather then min limit like this example:

```
CREATE TABLE EnitityX
(
Age int NOT NULL,
RecordId int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
CHECK (Age>6),
CHECK (Age<40),
CHECK (RecordId<6)
)
```

Comment: thanks for help, but i have to calculate age as a derived attirubute, i just have birthdate not age so i think @Dudu Markovitz answer will solve my problem.